# Swiftで莫大な数を使う

Tags: ios, swift

Int.maxよりも大きな値(20桁以上)を使いたいのですがどうすればできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html) を Swift から使用することができます。

```
import Foundation

let n1: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString("999")
let n2: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString("1000000")

let sum = n1.decimalNumberByAdding(n2)
```

ただ、 `NSDecimalNumber` は38桁までしか扱えないのでそれより大きい数の場合は、なにかしらの[外部ライブラリ](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BigInt%20Swift&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)に頼る必要があります。

Comment: 助かりました！
ありがとうございました